# How to draw on a picturebox and save it in Winforms C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, picturebox

I'm making a simple graphic editor in Windows Forms (C#), and I'm using a `PictureBox` for my canvas. I want to implement the "undo" functionality. I'm drawing using `System.Drawing.Graphics`. Here is my situation:

- If I use `picturebox.CreateGraphics()`, then I will see the drawing, but it won't actually be made on the image (if afterwards I called `pictureBox.Image.Save(...)`, the saved image would be blank).
- If I use `Graphics.FromImage(picturebox.Image)`, then the drawing will be actually made on the image, but I won't see anything.

How can I have both?

And how do I implement the undo functionality after that? I tried using `Save()` and `Restore()` on graphics, but it didn't work, maybe I misunderstood what these methods mean.

Comment: Yes, don't use CreateGraphics.  Try calling `pictureBox.Invalidate()` to update the image.

Comment: Cool, thanks, I didn't know that. However, I want every change on the graphics to immediately be visible. And I don't want to have to call `picturebBox.Invalidate()` after each graphics change :)

Comment: @LarsTech You're right, I thought I was going to have to call `pictureBox.Invalidate()` after each method call on the `Graphics` object. But I don't, I need to do it only after some concrete change. Thank you! Could you compose it into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid using CreateGraphics since that is a temporary drawing that can get erased by minimizing the form or having another form overlap the graphic area, etc.

To update the PictureBox, just invalidate it after you have an update to the drawing:

```
pictureBox1.Invalidate();
```

The Undo-Redo is a different beast. That requires you to keep a list of things to draw and in order to undo something, you remove the item from the list and redraw the whole thing again from the active list.

Comment: Where to put `pictureBox1.Invalidate();` to export it as jpeg? is in save button, paint, mousedown, etc.?

Comment: @AnjelloJoshua If exporting to a jpeg, you should probably use a Bitmap and draw on that (`Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(yourBitmap);` etc , and have the SaveButton call the save routine.  Never call `pictureBox1.Invalidate();` in the PictureBox's Paint event — that could make it lock up.

Comment: Ok. part of my program is creating a drawing pad. in running form the user draws and stays in panel/picturebox `CreateGraphics` shouldnt be use because it is temp. I wish you could help me to make drawing saveable.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65762544/saving-camera-shot-and-drawing-from-picturebox-to-jpeg?noredirect=1#comment116272140_65762544